# Invoke callback on liking

Tags: facebook

This code is totally from FB Development tutorial.
In my html file:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//WWW.localhost:3000//channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        })};

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            }
    );
</script>
```

As it is written in tutorial, Event subscribe should invoke alert each time button is clicked, but nothings happens.
Basically, I want to start AJAX put each time button clicked and count likes

Answer (score 0):

Event subscriber should be inside initializer, APP_ID should be string, testing on localhost requires to remove WWW:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//localhost:3000/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            }

 })};
```